# Modifying URLs in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

My application generates various urls based on Categories and Names of the products. For instance to browse products by category the url would be

```
localhost/category/Memory Cards
```

The problem is that spaces are converted to `%20`s. If I `urlencode` or `rawurlencode` the spaces are converted to `+` sign but `/` are also converted to `%xx` equivalent which results in invalid mapping of url to controllers.

I need all of my urls to be encoded with `+` sign instead of `spaces`. I could use a helper. However, I'd need to call helper method everywhere.

Can I use `hooks` to modify the HTML, scan all urls and replace `spaces` with `+` sign?

I need to decode the urls back to `spaces` from `+` signs as well. How could I do that?

And if you reckon my approach is all wrong, what would be an appropriate way of doing it??

Comment: What's wrong with `urldecode()`?

Comment: I'll have to call it in every method. I want a more generic way of doing like using it in a hook or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefered way of doing this is to have an additional field in the table (I usualy use "slug" for the field's name) that is a url-friendly version of the name (lowercased, and replace spaces and weird characters with dashes/underscores/whatever), just make sure to keep it unique, and then use that to generate the urls to products and to identify what product the request is about.

So your url would look like `localhost/category/memory-cards`.

You can use [`url_title()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) to generate the slugs